# How to Make Spark Streaming DStream as SQL table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

The aim here is as follows:

- read data from Socket using Spark Streaming every N seconds
- register received data as SQL table
- there will be more data read from HDFS etc as reference data, they will also be registered as SQL tables
- the idea is to perform arbitrary SQL queries on the combined streaming & reference data

Please see below code snippet. I see Data is written out to disk from "inside" the forEachRDD loop but the same registered SQL table's data is empty when written "outside" of forEachRDD loop.

Please give your opinion/suggestions to fix this. Also any other mechanism to achieve the above stated "aim" is welcome.

```
case class Record(id:Int, status:String, source:String)

object SqlApp2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SqlApp2").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    // Create the streaming context with a 10 second batch size
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))

    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)

    var alldata:DataFrame=sqlContext.emptyDataFrame
    alldata.registerTempTable("alldata")

    lines.foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[String], time: Time) => {
      import sqlContext.implicits._

      // Convert RDD[String] to DataFrame
      val data = rdd.map(w => {
        val words = w.split(" ")
        Record(words(0).toInt, words(1), words(2))}).toDF()

      // Register as table
      data.registerTempTable("alldata")
      data.save("inside/file"+System.currentTimeMillis(), "json", SaveMode.ErrorIfExists)  // this data is written properly
    })

    val dataOutside = sqlContext.sql("select * from alldata")
    dataOutside.save("outside/file"+System.currentTimeMillis(), "json", SaveMode.ErrorIfExists) // this data is empty, how to make the SQL table registered inside the forEachRDD loop visible for rest of application

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
```

Thanks & Regards

MK

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can have the create table only within a block like 'foreachRDD' unless you go the [Structured Streaming route](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html). With your approach, you could use a sliding window to keep a certain amount of data in your table. I have given the relevant code below.

```
// You could create a window of 1 minute to run your query
val windowedStream = lines.window(Seconds(60))

windowedStream.foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[String], time: Time) => {
  import sqlContext.implicits._
  val data = rdd.map(w => {
    val words = w.split(" ")
    Record(words(0).toInt, words(1), words(2))
  }).toDF()
  data.createOrReplaceTempView("alldata")

  // You can read your other data source and convert it into a DF table
  // and join with the 'alldata' table
  val dataInside = sqlContext.sql("select * from alldata")
  dataInside.show()
})
```

Hope this helps.

Please do note that Structured Streaming is in the initial phase and has very limited functionality.